# Cannot import tensorflow_text, and it throws a popup error message

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, conda

I am working in TensorFlow.

Importing TensorFlow is working fine, but whenever I try to import tensorflow_text there is this pop-up error:

[image: Error after importing tensorflow_text]

I tried reinstalling *TensorFlow-text*, but it didn't work.

Comment: Please provide some more details of the issue as what OS , Platform (Colab, Jupyter) and tensorflow, python version you are using while facing this issue. How did you install the tensorflow and what code line is showing this error?

Answer (score 0):

The error is stemming from a different issue than Tensorflow-text or TensorFlow installation per se.

As encountered by multiple users, this solution is evident to get the Python error resolved. It is related to modifying some root file names which are included in the Anaconda package. Here are the steps to do that:

Copy `libssl-1_1-x64 dlls` found in *Anaconda/DLLS* to `Anaconda/Library/bin`

However, as stated by an Anaconda maintainer [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9003#issuecomment-553529174),

> moving libssl dlls [sic] around like that is really not advisable. Those
> DLLs are duplicated because you have something fishy going on in your
> packages. There should not be any openssl [sic] DLLs in the DLLs folder.
> They should be in Library/bin.

1. Rename `Library\bin\libssl-1_1-x64.dll` to
   `Library\bin\libssl-1_1-x64.dll.org` (your are going to need it
   later.)
2. Copy `DLLs\libssl-1_1-x64.dll` to `Library\bin\libssl-1_1-x64.dll`
3. Update Python to version 3.7.1 or higher, for instance with `conda update python` This will remove the `DLLs\libssl-1_1-x64.dll` file.
4. Delete the current `Library\bin\libssl-1_1-x64.dll` file.
5. Rename `Library\bin\libssl-1_1-x64.dll.org` back to
   `Library\bin\libssl-1_1-x64.dll`. This is necessary because HTTP
   errors may occur in the next step otherwise.
6. Reinstall OpenSSL with `conda install openssl --force-reinstall` to
   ensure it's up to date again.
   You can also refer to this discussion [thread](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9003#issuecomment-553529174)
   If you find this useful, you may upvote / accept this for community benefit.

Comment: What is the actual (literal) folder name? `DLLS`, `DLLs`, or `dlls`? It may not matter in some parts of Windows, but perhaps in related pars, like [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway), [MSYS2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mingw-w64#MSYS2), [Cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin), and [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux).

Comment: This solution I provided is for Windows as in the error we can see the path name belongs to Windows. It is dll in small case , though.